# Hadoop installation: what is "This is comment for WebHCat Service (sic)"

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

Using Ambari, `This is comment for WebHcat Service` is the final selection in the “Services Selection” step.

If I don't select this service, then the `Customize Services` step hangs indefinitely. It doesn't matter which other services are selected.

If I select it, then the `Customize Services` step functions normally, but the installation will stop on step four with the error message:

> “org.apache.ambari.server.controller.spi.SystemException:
>   An internal system exception occurred:
>   Configuration with tag `version1439256707212` exists for `webhcat-site`

This is on a clean install, for a single node SLES 11 SP3 server.

What is the service `This is comment for WebHcat Service`, and why is it a comment instead of a service name?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a fresh install, it's strange your getting configuration already exists errors. I would try to clean your ambari server instance by running:

```
 sudo ambari-server reset
```

This will reset the postgres database that ambari-server uses, giving you a clean slate to retry another cluster install.